# Can you read this, or at least help me identify the characters?

Tags: translation, reading

Can you help me read these, or help me identify the characters? They're written on the backing paper of a scroll painting, probably from my great grandmother from about 1925. I’ve tried two different OCR packages and get nothing. [Here are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtLje.jpg) a picture of the painting, the inscriptions on its back, and my attempts to trace the inscriptions for use with OCR.

[image: image of first inscription]
[image: image of second inscription]

Comment: All I can make out of is 梅: ? ? 晚春

Comment: maybe “梅梅大x” & “皖x”, imo 

Comment: methinks, great grandma won't win any calligraphy prizes! I asked someone who is usually good at this to look, but no, undecipherable! Personally, I think the first 3 may be: 枚二大，but I am not a reliable source for deciphering squiggles!

Comment: Thank you so much for trying! You are doing much better at it than I can. I hope someone can still make sense of it.

Comment: By the way, where is the first inscription located on the painting? It doesn't seem to be the one right above the seal. I suppose the location of the writing might give it some context that could help determining its meaning.

Comment: Both inscriptions are on the outside of the backing paper.

Answer (score 1):

I actually a bit skeptical about this calligraphy, because the semantic (meaning) is a bit confusing, is it 普通话 or 白话 or 福建话 or any other dialects? If it is 普通话, then..

From last to first, I can only identify the last 4 characters, that is `晚春` wan3 chun2, means `night spring`.

The middle one might be `大念` means `big aspiration` or something, since `念` is like `怀念` or `念想`. It is illogical to say that the middle one is `贪`, because `贪污` means embezzlement (in political context) and even `包含` in `含满` and `包含` . So I'll go with `念 nian4` instead of `贪 tan1` and `含 han2`.

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure about the three characters in the middle, perhaps 梅-二-大-？（含？舍？）-晚-春